# How to remove only one of repeated chars in string using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, string

I have a string with repeated chars like : **'CANADA'**. 
And I am trying to get the string which removed only one of repeated chars : 
**'CNADA', 'CANDA', 'CANAD'**.

I've tried it with subString, but it returned the part of string removed.
Also I've tried it with reduce, but it ended up removing all the repeated chars ('CND').

What is the way of removing only one char at time?
The results can be stored in array. (results = ['CNADA', 'CANDA', 'CANAD'])

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to get the string whose only first repeating character gets removed?

Comment: What if the string is `Mississippi`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by utilizing the second parameter of [`String#indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) which specifies the position from which to start the search. Here in a `while` loop, and using a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to remove dulplicates before returning.

```js
function getReplaceOptions(str, char) {
  let res = [], i = str.indexOf(char, 0);
  while (i !== -1) {
    res.push(str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(++i));
    i = str.indexOf(char, i)
  }
  return Array.from(new Set(res))
}

console.log(getReplaceOptions('CANADA', 'A'));
console.log(getReplaceOptions('Mississippi', 's'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first count all the occurrences in the string. Later you can iterate over the script and if the count is greater than 1 you can remove that character.

```js
const theString = 'CANADA'
const letterCount = {}
const resultArr = []

for (var i = 0; i < theString.length; i++) {
  const theLetter = theString.charAt(i)
  if(letterCount[theLetter]){
    letterCount[theLetter] = letterCount[theLetter] + 1
  }
  else{
    letterCount[theLetter] = 1
  }
}
console.log(letterCount)
for (var i = 0; i < theString.length; i++) {
  const theLetter = theString.charAt(i)
  if(letterCount[theLetter] && letterCount[theLetter] > 1){
   resultArr.push(theString.substr(0, i) + theString.substr(i + 1))
  }
}

console.log(resultArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use some `Array` magic to remove duplicate characters:

```js
function removeDuplicateCharacters(value) {

    // convert string to array and loop through each character
    return String(value).split('').filter(function(char, index, all) {

        // return false if char found at a different index
        return (index === all.indexOf(char));
    })
    .join(''); // convert back to a string
}
```

```js
// returns `CAND`
removeDuplicateCharacters('CANADA');

// returns `helo wrd`
removeDuplicateCharacters('hello world');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove only the first repeating character then you can use [`matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAllhttps://) here as:

Just see the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll#browser_compatibility) before using this

```js
const str = 'CANADA';
const firstRepeatedChar = 'A';
const result = [];

for (let { index } of str.matchAll(firstRepeatedChar)) {
  result.push(str.slice(0, index) + str.slice(index + 1));
}

console.log(result);
```

---

**NOTE: If you want to search for the first repeating character then remove it, then you can do as:**

```js
const str = 'CANADA';

let firstRepeatedChar = '';
const set = new Set();
for (let i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
  if (!set.has(str[i])) {
    set.add(str[i]);
  } else {
    firstRepeatedChar = str[i];
    break;
  }
}

const result = [];
for (let { index } of str.matchAll(firstRepeatedChar)) {
  result.push(str.slice(0, index) + str.slice(index + 1));
}

console.log(result);
```